# Using Boost.Phoenix's operator ->*

Tags: c++, boost, boost-phoenix

I'm playing around with Phoenix v3 trying to figure out whether we should standardize on it instead of the current mix of Bind and Lambda. From the documentation I got the impression that it should be possible to simplify some expressions.

Currently I'm stuck on the usage of the ->* operator in combination with the STL algos. The following will compile (Visual Studio 2008 SP1) but not give the expected output:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/mem_fn.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::phoenix;
using namespace boost::phoenix::arg_names;

struct A
{
  void f() const { cout << "A"; };
};
struct B
{
  A a() { return A(); };
};

int main()
{
  vector<A> va(1);
  for_each(va.begin(), va.end(), bind(mem_fn(&A::f), arg1));
  for_each(va.begin(), va.end(), arg1->*&A::f);

  vector<B> vb(1);
  for_each(vb.begin(), vb.end(), bind(mem_fn(&A::f), bind(mem_fn(&B::a), arg1)));
  return 0;
}
```

Running this example will print out 'A' twice, both times for the bind-based loops.
So here are my questions:

- What should I change in order to have the operator-based loop actually call A::f?
- How could I change the double-bind loop using operators?
- Anyone know why VS2008 is always complaining when you don't specify mem_fn in these cases? I always get warning C4180 (qualifier applied to function type has no meaning; ignored).

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: Warning C4180 is benign -- ignore it in code that isn't yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also not too good at phoenix but I think you cannot use the ->* operator the way you want it to use.
If you change your example to

```
...
    vector<A*> va;
    va.push_back(new A);
    for_each(va.begin(), va.end(), bind(mem_fn(&A::f), arg1));
    for_each(va.begin(), va.end(), (arg1->*&A::f)());
...
```

you will get two times A. In the examples I only found examples with pointers so I guess you can only use the phoenix ->* operator with pointers. Which should be ok as the operator ->* binds to pointers.
From the Spec in 5.5:

> The binary operator ->* binds its second operand, which shall be of
>   type “pointer to member of T” (where T is a completely-defined class
>   type) to its first operand, which shall be of type “pointer to T” or
>   “pointer to a class of which T is an unambiguous and accessible base
>   class

Comment: Yes indeed, that works! Now I also know how to do it with values: (&arg1->*&A::f)()

Comment: And the double-bind can be replaced by: (&((&arg1->*&B::a)())->*&A::f)(), not that I think it's that much clearer...

Comment: @Ben : No, that invokes UB, unless you're compiling with VC++ which allows that as a non-standard compiler extension. I'll post a full answer with more details.

Comment: @ildjarn: Non-standard behavior that breaks conforming programs isn't an extension, it's a **bug**.

Comment: @BenVoigt : It doesn't break conforming programs, it allows non-conforming programs to work -- hence extension.

Comment: @ildjarn: This is the "feature" of binding non-const references to temporaries, correct?  SO users have encountered all kinds of breakage of conforming programs resulting from that.

Comment: @BenVoigt : Indeed, that's the so-called feature. I wasn't aware that it could break conforming code (I've not encountered that yet).

Answer (score 4):

Given:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>

struct A
{
    void f() const { std::cout << "A\n"; };
};

struct B
{
    A a() const { return A(); };
};
```

The first one is an easy fix:

```
int main()
{
    using boost::phoenix::arg_names::arg1;

    std::vector<A> va(1);
    std::for_each(va.begin(), va.end(), (&arg1->*&A::f)());
}
```

Regarding `operator->*`, the Phoenix docs [clearly state](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/modules/operator.html#phoenix.modules.operator.member_pointer_operator):

> The left hand side of the member pointer operator must be an actor returning a pointer type.

Consequently, when given an object (in this case an `A&`), one must take the address of said object in order to use `operator->*` -- hence `&arg1`. (Also, because Phoenix actors are lazy, one must use an extra set of parenthesis in order to obtain the eager functor rather than the lazy functor.)

---

The second one is not quite as easy, as one cannot use only operators -- because we must have an actor representing a *pointer* in order to use `operator->*`, we would need to take the address of the result of `B::a`, but the result of `B::a` is an rvalue and taking the address of any rvalue is illegal. We have two options:

1. Store the result of `B::a` into a variable, making it an lvalue, and consequently making it legal to take the address of. This can be accomplished using [`phoenix::let`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/modules/scope/let.html):

   ```
   int main()
   {
       using boost::phoenix::let;
       using boost::phoenix::arg_names::arg1;
       using boost::phoenix::local_names::_a;

       std::vector<B> vb(1);
       std::for_each(
           vb.begin(),
           vb.end(),
           (let(_a = (&arg1->*&B::a)())[(&_a->*&A::f)()])
       );
   }
   ```

   Obviously this is pretty ugly.
2. Use [`phoenix::bind`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/modules/bind.html) instead of `operator->*`, since it works equally well with references and pointers, obviating the need to take the address of the result of `B::a`:

   ```
   int main()
   {
       using boost::phoenix::bind;
       using boost::phoenix::arg_names::arg1;

       std::vector<B> vb(1);
       std::for_each(vb.begin(), vb.end(), bind(&A::f, (&arg1->*&B::a)()));
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Looks like I was about to be bitten by the 'features' of VC++ again. Good to know as otherwise our set of test compilers (GCC and ICC) would have had to catch it. Looking back on my question I actually thought the ->* operator could be used as a convenient replacement for bind. Seems I was wrong and I think I'll keep using (phoenix) bind for this kind of stuff. I don't want to worry about iterating over a collection of values or pointers.

Comment: +1 for the really elaborate answer. That helped me a lot to understand phoenix better.